# second value read from friebase datbase giving null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

im trying to read values from "images/Scholar_id/images-values" by reading from another node called "QnA/Answers/Questionid/pushkey/id----childs(scholar_id)" ,i'm trying to loop inside from QnA node and getting all values os Scholar_ids and use this values to retrieve all values from "images" but it giving only single value and for other values it reading null.

```
  DatabaseReference answersRef = database.getReference("QnA/Answers/" + pushkey);
        List<String> scholarIds = new ArrayList<>();


// Retrieve all the child nodes under "QnA/Answers"
        answersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // Loop through all the child nodes
                for (DataSnapshot answerSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    // Get the Scholar_id value from the child node

                    for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : answerSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        letssee = childSnapshot.child("Scholar_id").getValue(String.class);
                        break;
                    }
                    scholarIds.add(letssee);
                 
                

                }


                for (String scholarId : scholarIds) {
                    DatabaseReference imagesRef = database.getReference().child("images").child(scholarId);
                    imagesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            String imageUrl = dataSnapshot.child("images").getValue(String.class);
                            System.out.println("Scholar ID: " + scholarId + ", Image URL: " + imageUrl);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            System.out.println("Error reading image data: " + databaseError.getMessage());
                        }
                    });
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println("Error reading answer data: " + databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });

I tried above code which printing only single value for Scholar_ids and for second it printing  null.

Below I mentioned my Datbase structure

{
  "QnA": {
    "Answers": {
    "-NOwjqMSTyj3n99suf_P": {
        "-NP6Bqe17QyjQkK-WzAG": {
          "11111513456": {
            "Answer": "Hello this is remo",
            "Answer_time": "25 Feb 23",
            "Scholar_id": "11111513456",
            "answer_name": "remo21",
            "images": "\"\""
        },
        "-NP6CP_5CccC73XSla8o": {
          " 11111513710": {
            "Answer": "Answer by sohail",
            "Answer_time": "25 Feb 23",
            "Scholar_id": " 11111513710",
            "answer_name": "Yobro",
            "images": "\"\""
    },
  "images": {
    "11111513450": {
      "images": "second"
    },
    "11111513456": {
      "images": "first"
    },
    "11111513710": {
      "images": "third"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Instead of describing what your database looks like, please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I export it form from firebase